# is it possible to get lat long of annotations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, maps

I am using iPhone native maps to my application. I have a set of lat, long , title & subtitle in a array and plotting them to map with annotations. When I click to the annotations title & subtitle are shown. Is there any way to get lat, long of a annotation when I click to the annotation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Implement the Method `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` of the `MKMapViewDelegate` - Protocol ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)). In there, you cann access the lat & long by accessing the `annotation` - Property of the `MkAnnotationView`, which conforms to the `MkAnnotation` - Protocol ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) and therefore has a property called `coordinate`.

**Update:**
The following code sample prints the lat/lon of an annotation after selecting it on the map:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
   NSLog(@"Latitude: %f", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude);
   NSLog(@"Longitude: %f", view.annotation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how can I add direction to my iPhone apps. I tried google api v3, but failed to show direction because it returns to the html. I also tried cloud made SDK, but in free registration they show advertise. I also tried route-me, But they did not give any good solution about this. So how can I show direction in my iPhone apps?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the following method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

MapAnnotation *annotation = (MapAnnotation *)view.annotation; //MapAnnotation your class     which conform to MKAnnotation

float lattude = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
float longtude = annotation.coordinate.longitude;



}
```

in the class which conform to MKMapViewDelegate

Comment: can you tell me how can I add direction to my iPhone apps. I tried google api v3, but failed to show direction because it returns to the html. I also tried cloud made SDK, but in free registration they show advertise. I also tried route-me, But they did not give any good solution about this. So how can I show direction in my iPhone apps?

Comment: @Zubair
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:GOOGLE_MAP_URL,startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; and GoOGLE_MAP_URL = http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@ ,open this url in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2:0**

Add MKMapViewDelegate.

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView){      

let currentAnnotationLattitude = view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude

let currentAnnotationLongitude = view.view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude
        }
```

Note: It works for multiple pin Annotations in a single map View. This delegate will provide annotation view's current lattitude and longitude.